# Tony sent Pepper to get some files off his work computer. Why couldn't he do that himself?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, computers, iron-man-2008

In Iron Man 1, around 1:30:00, Tony sends Pepper into his office to download some files off his work computer.

1. Why couldn't he do that himself?
2. Why couldn't he connect to it remotely over some kind of corporate VPN? I'd think Stark would be all about telework.

Comment: It needn't have been a VPN - it could have been over an "actual" private network, or possibly even a secure protocol over an insecure network.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

1. Tony did not want to tip his hand to Obadiah Stane that he was suspicious of him. Obadiah had been cordial up to that point (and given that Obadiah tries to kill him afterward, Tony's fears would have been well founded). Since Tony was not a frequent visitor to the building where Obadiah's office was located, and Pepper was, it made more sense for her to go.
2. VPNs were uncommon in 2008 and probably not that well known by Hollywood writers or the general movie-going audience. Also, the Internet has changed a *lot* since 2008. To put this into perspective, consider [this line from the movie](https://web.archive.org/web/20161026075622/http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=iron-man):

   > I don't wanna see this on your MySpace page.

   MySpace was still a larger social network than Facebook at the time

Comment: Indeed, it does appear he preferred to work from his home office, so it follows that he would rather stick out if he were to go into the office. Thanks.

On the other hand, he was able to get JARVIS to download specs from the Seraphim Tactical Satellite for the alloy used in the Mark 3, so it would appear he did have some kind of remote access.

Comment: The problem with a corporate VPN is that, well, it's administered by the corporation. Stane *runs the corporation*. It would be easy for him to tap any suspicious access like that.

Comment: Re: the web being very different in 2008. Yeah, in 2008, the first mobile web pages were made. Think of that. The first iPhone was in its first year, and before it, no one had web page designs for screens smaller than a 800x600 monitor.

Comment: @JosephHansen Of course, they had them before. There were sites built with XHTML Mobile, before that there were sites based on WML. iPhone just speed up what had already been developing for quite some time for feature phones, smartphones, and PDAs.

Comment: @Malcolm Yes, but if you remember using or developing on those websites, you remember they weren’t common, weren’t commonly used, and could barely be called a website. Most people wouldn’t recognize a mobile website from before 2009.

Comment: @JosephHansen A website is a website. They did exist and were quite useful when you had no other alternative. Arguing whether some people would recognize them or not and such is completely subjective. Yeah, I spent quite some time on WAP forums back in the day, had my own mobile site, also wrote lots of Java ME apps, by the way. That's why I get rather upset when people start claiming that nothing existed before iPhone just because there weren't aware of that. iPhone was good and did make large screen mobile devices more popular, but let's not credit it for what it didn't actually do.

Comment: _"VPNs were uncommon in 2008"_ ???? Not sure what the relevance is either of mobile webpages or the reigning social media entity of the era. If nothing else, remote computing has been a staple of this kind of fiction, including the comic source material, for decades and decades and decades. I find it preprosterous (:P) to presume that audiences wouldn't understand it, and therefore unlikely that this was the reason that producers shied away from it in the film. Point 1 is good - it's because this is drama

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I think it's a case of [Reality Is Unrealistic](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RealityIsUnrealistic). There's a conscious effort in Iron Man (and most early 2000s superhero movies) to make the story feel grounded and like something that could happen in the real world. If audiences weren't familiar with real-world remote computing technologies at the time, they would assume it's a fictional technology, and that would hurt what the filmmakers were trying to achieve.

Comment: @JustinLardinois Granted. If put this way, it might make point 2 more swallowable.

Comment: @Cadence: so not *corporate* VPN, just SSH or SFTP to his own computer.  Security + authentication of both sides to each other (for pre-existing computers that know about each other via RSA public keys) was a fully solved problem well before 2008.  Tony would only need a VPN if he wanted to stop Stane from even knowing that he was connecting to his main computer.  But if he's willing to say in front of Stane that Pepper should get some files, that rules that out trying to keep that fact secret.  I think @ Justin's point about audiences think it would need future tech is on the money.

Comment: @Cadence, not really true. There were mobile web pages prior to 2008. But they were [WAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Application_Protocol) pages. And WAP was perfectly adapted for usage via mobile (non-touch devices). And it was selling point of iPhone that it's HTML-capable, and can show pages from the real Web (they were not optimised at all, [iPhone just rendered it in "standard" desktop resolution and you had to zoom it afterwards](http://movies.apple.com/media/us/iphone/2009/tours/apple-iphone3gs-features-safari-us-20090608_r640-9cie.mov)).

Comment: How would retrieving files reveal more than asking someone else to retrieve them?  Could it be that he wanted to conceal his ability to do remote access?  I don’t feel competent to answer (don’t recall that scene at all) but seems to me fetching files quietly would reveal less than asking someone else to do it.

Answer (score 14):

Machavity’s point #1 is a good explanation, but I don’t think point #2 is on the money. Although VPNs might not have been as common in 2008, remote access was definitely well established. I was personally using ssh as far back as 1999 for remote access to my employer’s computers, and an ISDN connection as far back as 1995—and I’m no billionaire. Tony Stark would for sure have had remote access to Stark Industries’ internal network.

However, the files to be copied were very large. Transferring them over Tony’s remote connection would probably cause a large and sustained increase in the connection’s bandwidth metrics. Stark Industries’ IT security staff would have a network dashboard with a graph that would make the increase obvious, and the increase might trip alarms.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the accepted answer:

After Tony announced that Stark Industries was exiting weapons production he was ousted as CEO by his own Board of Directors, who secured an injunction to lock him out.  Tony owned a controlling interest in the company, and eventually would have been able to prevail in a dispute with the board, but at that moment he was effectively in exile. Pepper, however, remained a Stark Industries employee.